# Cannot find module 'quasar/dist/babel-transforms/imports.js with VueJs and Quasar

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, babeljs, quasar

I have installed
`@vue/cli 4.5.13`

and create an app with vue2
`$ vue create my-app`

After that I install Quasar following the documentation:
Vue CLI Quasar Plugin (https://v1.quasar.dev/start/vue-cli-plugin)

```
$ cd my-app
$ npm install --save-dev vue-cli-plugin-quasar@3
$ vue invoke quasar
```

Then when I run `npm run serve`

I get the error
Full error:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                                                                   10:08:32 PM

 error  in ./src/main.js

Syntax Error: Error: Cannot find module 'quasar/dist/babel-transforms/imports.js'
Require stack:
- /Users/danielkogut/Documents/projects/projeto-vue/node_modules/vue-cli-plugin-quasar/lib/get-devland-file.js
- /Users/danielkogut/Documents/projects/projeto-vue/node_modules/vue-cli-plugin-quasar/lib/loader.transform-quasar-imports.js
- /Users/danielkogut/Documents/projects/projeto-vue/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js
- /Users/danielkogut/Documents/projects/projeto-vue/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js
- /Users/danielkogut/Documents/projects/projeto-vue/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js
- /Users/danielkogut/Documents/projects/projeto-vue/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js
- /Users/danielkogut/Documents/projects/projeto-vue/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js
- /Users/danielkogut/Documents/projects/projeto-vue/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js
- /Users/danielkogut/Documents/projects/projeto-vue/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/serve.js
- /Users/danielkogut/Documents/projects/projeto-vue/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js
- /Users/danielkogut/Documents/projects/projeto-vue/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js


 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.178:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js

Syntax Error: Error: Cannot find module 'quasar/dist/babel-transforms/imports.js'
Require stack:
- /Users/danielkogut/Documents/projects/projeto-vue/node_modules/vue-cli-plugin-quasar/lib/get-devland-file.js
- /Users/danielkogut/Documents/projects/projeto-vue/node_modules/vue-cli-plugin-quasar/lib/loader.transform-quasar-imports.js
- /Users/danielkogut/Documents/projects/projeto-vue/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js
- /Users/danielkogut/Documents/projects/projeto-vue/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js
- /Users/danielkogut/Documents/projects/projeto-vue/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js
- /Users/danielkogut/Documents/projects/projeto-vue/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js
- /Users/danielkogut/Documents/projects/projeto-vue/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js
- /Users/danielkogut/Documents/projects/projeto-vue/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js
- /Users/danielkogut/Documents/projects/projeto-vue/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/serve.js
- /Users/danielkogut/Documents/projects/projeto-vue/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js
- /Users/danielkogut/Documents/projects/projeto-vue/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js


 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.178:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

I tried to install `npm install @babel/core --save`

But It shows a huge error that I will post just the begging:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/danielkogut/Documents/projects/projeto-test-vue1/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/Cellar/node/16.10.0/bin/node /Users/danielkogut/Documents/projects/projeto-test-vue1/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/danielkogut/.node-gyp/16.10.0/include/node -I/Users/danielkogut/.node-gyp/16.10.0/src -I/Users/danielkogut/.node-gyp/16.10.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/danielkogut/.node-gyp/16.10.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/danielkogut/.node-gyp/16.10.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/danielkogut/.node-gyp/16.10.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/danielkogut/.node-gyp/16.10.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o ../src/libsass/src/ast.cpp
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "projeto-test-vue1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "quasar": "^1.0.0",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-cli-plugin-quasar": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
}
```

vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    quasar: {
      importStrategy: 'kebab',
      rtlSupport: false
    }
  },
  transpileDependencies: [
    'quasar'
  ]
}
```

I dont know what to do, at all.
Help me! Thanks...

Comment: Because we can't see the rest of the node-sass error, it's hard to tell. More than likely your version of node is incompatible with the version of node-sass you have. [Here's a post on GitHub about the version compatibility](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2549#issuecomment-851609577)